# Using i18n.detectLanguage() in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was reading [Moxilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n/detectLanguage) and found the function i18n.detectLanguage(). The document states that it can be used in the following way:

```
var detectingLanguages = browser.i18n.detectLanguage(
  text                  // string
)
```

However, when I try to use the code above in my Vue application I just get variable not defined on `browser`.

How can I use the builtin i18n API which should be supported in all browsers except Safari?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API is only available in browser extensions, not for scripts on the page.

You can see that in the breadcrumbs of the page:

```
Mozilla > Add-ons > Browser Extensions > JavaScript APIs > i18n > i18n.detectLanguage()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And also the URL:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n/detectLanguage
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```